# Converting string to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime, typeconverter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date time format from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232732/date-time-format-from-string)

Does anyone know how I could convert the following string to a `DateTime` value in C# ?

```
"Thu Nov 15 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (E. Africa Standard Time)"
```

Comment: Also look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net

Comment: @Bhushan Firake. i have tried DateTime.ParseExact(string,format,format provider) but what format should i use for the above

Comment: @lafama: You can go through this article  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only have strings ending with `"GMT+0300 (E. Africa Standard Time)"`, you can try:

```
string dateString = "Thu Nov 15 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (E. Africa Standard Time)";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT+0300 (E. Africa Standard Time)'", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The meanings of the specifiers are as follows:

- "ddd" The abbreviated name of the day of the week.
- "MMM" The abbreviated name of the month.
- "dd" The day of the month, from 01 through 31.
- "yyyy" The year as a four-digit number.
- "HH" The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
- "mm" The minute, from 00 through 59.
- "ss" The second, from 00 through 59.
- ":" The time separator.
- "string", 'string' Literal string delimiter.

You can find out more about different format specifiers in the MSDN article named [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Moreover, if you want to parse `"GMT+0300 (E. Africa Standard Time)"` part too, I think you should implement a way to parse them yourself. I don't think there's a specifier for that.

Comment: In principle your list of specifiers should also mention: • `":"` The `TimeSeparator` of the format provider you use; will translate to `:` for the invariant culture. Translates to `.` for some other cultures.

Comment: @Jeppe: You're right, I forgot that one. Adding it right now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should Africa Standart Time culture info use for yours';

```
CultureInfo( "af-ZA", false );
```

But your string is really complex for converting to `DateTime`. For me it looks imposible to convert to `DateTime` perfectly. But we can some rehabilitation in your string. For example, if your string was like this; `"11/15/2012 00:00:00"` you can convert it like this;

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Programs
{
    public class Program
    {      
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "11/15/2012 00:00:00";
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("af-ZA"));
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

[`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

[`DateTime.ParseExact Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(yourDateTimeString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle (E. Africa Standard Time).

Assuming that UTC=GMT you can also get the time zone part, just remove not important parts of your string

```
string t = Regex.Replace("Thu Nov 15 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (E. Africa Standard Time)", "([(].+?[)])", "");
t= t.Replace("GMT", "").Trim();

DateTime a = DateTime.ParseExact(t, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```